# SP2013 Delimited values to other columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, multiple-values

Here's an interesting one:  I have a list where one text column accepts multiple delimited values.  (By that, I mean multiple values separated by delimiters.)  Is there a calculated feature where I can take each value and put it in its own column?  For example, if I had the values " a,b,c,d,e," in the text column, and five other columns that could accept the values separately - Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIND() function in the calculated column split the value.

Here is a similar post for your reference:

[Split a text based on delimiter and add items to a sharepoint list using SPD workflow](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acb1abb3-20fa-45d1-9049-036798116abf/split-a-text-based-on-delimiter-and-add-items-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-spd-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)